# Changing user fields in Unity Firebase

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

Currently I am using firebase for my mobile database and my scheme looks like this

```
root
.
..Users
    .
    ...UserID
         .
         .....username:"null
```

I am using the current query to try to change one of the fields(username) however it does not seem to be working.
query:

```
_usernameref = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users")
                    .Child(auth.CurrentUser.UserId)
                    .Child("username");
_usernameref.SetValueAsync("Matt");
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong, I am fairly new to unity and firebase.

Comment: Use proper code formatting to post here & post your screenshot of firebase schema.

Comment: Change **GetReference("users") > GetReference("Users")**. Notice the capital U.